# Keep Entire Text From Changing

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have been trying to make a font type app for iOS in Xcode. It alters the normal text into emoji and unicode type letters and there are several different font variations to choose from. Right now, every time a new font is chosen, it changes the whole text field to that one selected font. But I'm trying to make it so that it doesn't effect the whole text field when a new font is selected, only the words that will be typed from that point on. I would appreciate if someone could help me with the code that would allow this. I would think its very easy but just not sure what to do.

An example app that does what my app does: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/textizer-fonts-fun-looking/id563544682?mt=8

An example app that does what i want my app to do: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/better-fonts-free-cool-new/id735011588?mt=8

Thanks in advance!

***Edit: My question is different because others are referring to actual fonts in the code and program. My situation is totally different. This is a special kind of app and the "font" is actually unicode symbols which is all the same language to a computer. So im actually just trying to make xcode and the app change without clearing the last symbol effect on the keyboard. It just like normal typing, and would actually be normal if it didn't change after a new one is selected. Not sure why the whole text box changes to the font that is selected, but i would think that its really easy to just add a line of code that doesn't make it change all the letters. If you just checked my links you would easily be able to see. Thanks again and sorry for the confusion. All help and code is appreciated.